# how do i group a List<int> and return a List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have a list of ints. I want to group the list and create a new list that contains only the grouped by number that meets a certain condition. this is what i have so far. the declarating for membersList is List

```
int rows = 5;

List<int> memberKeys = memberKeysList
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .Where(x => x.Count() == rows)
  .ToList();
```

Its complaining about converting from groupedby list to a list.

Comment: In your example you are getting back a list of groups, not a list of ints.  If you want the contents of one of the groups you need to select just one of those groups (your `Where` could match multiple groups).  If you just want to use the first group that matches your condition change your `Where` to `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `Select` the `Key` to get the number like:

```
List<int> memberKeys = memberKeysList.GroupBy(x => x)
                           .Where(x => x.Count() == rows)
                           .Select(grp => grp.Key)
                           .ToList();
```

If you are not going to explicitly select they `Key` *(or the number)*, then the result of `GroupBy` clause would be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`